# NoSuchDefinitionException when using struts2 with tiles plugin. All previous questions checked

Tags: java, jsp, struts2, apache-tiles

Im trying to use tiles with struts 2 and get a NoSuchDefinitionException. None of the solutions on stackoverflow or google fixed my issue so i decided to post a new question.
below is the configuration for struts  and tiles. Im using sample test pages which are not complete.

a) Web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">
  <display-name>ezviewocean</display-name>
  <description>EZ-View Ocean</description>
        <context-param>
            <param-name> org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.DEFINITIONS_CONFIG</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/tiles.xml</param-value>
        </context-param>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.apache.struts2.tiles.StrutsTilesListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
    <filter>
        <filter-name>struts-prepare</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>struts-prepare</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>login.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

b)struts.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>

<!DOCTYPE struts PUBLIC
    "-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Struts Configuration 2.3//EN"
    "http://struts.apache.org/dtds/struts-2.3.dtd">

<struts>
    <constant name="struts.enable.DynamicMethodInvocation" value="false" />
    <constant name="struts.devMode" value="true"/>
    <constant name="struts.custom.i18n.resources" value="ApplicationResources"/>

    <package name="default" extends="struts-default" namespace="/">
        <result-types>
         <result-type name="tiles" 
         class="org.apache.struts2.views.tiles.TilesResult" />
        </result-types>
        <action name="login" method="execute"
            class="com.schenker.ocean.actions.LoginAction">
            <result name="success" type="tiles">/baseLayout</result>
            <result name="input">/login.jsp</result>
            <result name="fail">/login.jsp</result>
        </action>
    </package>
</struts>
```

b.5) tiles.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>

<!DOCTYPE tiles-definitions PUBLIC
   "-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Tiles Configuration 2.0//EN"
   "http://tiles.apache.org/dtds/tiles-config_2_0.dtd">

<tiles-definitions>

   <definition name="baseLayout" template="/baseLayout.jsp">
      <put-attribute name="title"  value="Template"/>
      <put-attribute name="header" value="/header.jsp"/>
      <put-attribute name="leftmenu"   value="/leftmenu.jsp"/>
      <put-attribute name="body"   value="/body.jsp"/>
      <put-attribute name="footer"   value="/footer.jsp"/>
   </definition>

   <definition name="view" extends="baseLayout">
      <put-attribute name="title"  value="View"/>
      <put-attribute name="body"   value="/viewBody.jsp"/>      
   </definition>

   <definition name="assign" extends="baseLayout">
      <put-attribute name="title"  value="Assign"/>
      <put-attribute name="body"   value="/assignBody.jsp"/>      
   </definition>

</tiles-definitions>
```

c)baseLayout.jsp

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://tiles.apache.org/tags-tiles" prefix="tiles"%>
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
   "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>

<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title><tiles:insertAttribute name="title" ignore="true" />
</title>
</head>

<body>
   <tiles:insertAttribute name="header" /><br/>
   <hr/>
   <tiles:insertAttribute name="leftMenu" /><br/>
   <hr/>
   <tiles:insertAttribute name="body" /><br/>
   <hr/>
   <tiles:insertAttribute name="footer" /><br/>
</body>
</html>
```

below is the stack trace.

```
Stacktraces

org.apache.tiles.definition.NoSuchDefinitionException: /baseLayout.tiles
    org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.render(BasicTilesContainer.java:625)
    org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.render(BasicTilesContainer.java:321)
    org.apache.struts2.views.tiles.TilesResult.doExecute(TilesResult.java:105)
    org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.StrutsResultSupport.execute(StrutsResultSupport.java:186)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.executeResult(DefaultActionInvocation.java:371)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:275)
    org.apache.struts2.interceptor.DeprecationInterceptor.intercept(DeprecationInterceptor.java:41)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    org.apache.struts2.interceptor.debugging.DebuggingInterceptor.intercept(DebuggingInterceptor.java:256)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.DefaultWorkflowInterceptor.doIntercept(DefaultWorkflowInterceptor.java:167)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.validator.ValidationInterceptor.doIntercept(ValidationInterceptor.java:265)
    org.apache.struts2.interceptor.validation.AnnotationValidationInterceptor.doIntercept(AnnotationValidationInterceptor.java:68)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
```

I tried to debug the application and checked what value was being sent to TilesResult.class and figured its exactly the same as defined in struts.xml.. sooooo why didnt it pick up that configuration from tiles.xml?

Comment: Remove `/` from result configuration.

Comment: it didnt work @AleksandrM

Comment: What exception did you get? Seems that you are missing `TilesServlet` in your web.xml.

Comment: @AleksandrM Im using struts 2 and tiles plugin for struts 2. Dosent the struts2 StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter do the same thing as tilesservlet?

Comment: Nope. `StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter` knows nothing about tiles.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using .tiles in your results then you must define a configuration file for Tiles that maps each of those entries to a JSP.

In your code you have:

```
<result name="success" type="tiles">/baseLayout</result>
```

in order for it to work, you need to add a tiles.xml file with something like:

```
<tiles-definitions>
  <definition name="somelayout" template="/WEB-INF/jsp/baseLayout.jsp" />
</tiles-definitions>
```

Alternatively, do not use Tiles and use the JSP directly by replacing the .tiles by .jsp in the result definition XML.

You might also have to load Tiles explicitly in the web.xml:

```
 <servlet>
    <servlet-name>tiles</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.apache.tiles.web.startup.TilesServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.DEFINITIONS_CONFIG</param-name>
        <param-value>
            /WEB-INF/tiles.xml,
        </param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>2</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
```

to make sure that tiles requests are handled correctly.

Comment: If the definition name is `somelayout` then you need to use the same name in result also.

Comment: I forgot to post my tiles.xml. Sorry Please take a look now

Comment: Did you see log messages about Tiles being loaded? You might have to load it explicitly in web.xml.

Comment: @MikeLaren how can i explicitly load it? this is the only out of place text in the console but i thought its not related to tiles.    SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.

Comment: I updated the answer with a code snippet showing how to load the Tiles servlet. The `org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder` might be a problem with missing dependencies or maybe the SLF4J is not configured to route to some other logger like log4j.